# Hover sobre botón de Bootstrap no funciona como debería, solo se aplica sobre los elementos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, diseño, material-design

Tengo unos botones con bootstrap 4 y mdb, estoy intentando que al pasar con el mouse tanto el icono como el texto se animen, pero solo funcionan si paso por encima de cada uno de ellos y no sobre el botón.

**Código**

```css
.primary_color {
  background-color: #dc1921;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.81rem;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #fff;
}

.icono img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 35px;
}

.icono img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.icono:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

b {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

b:hover {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn primary_color waves-effect waves-light">
     <span class="icono"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7s0Ddbj.png" alt="Iconos"></span><br>
     <b>LANDSCAPE</b>
    </button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda, me funciona ahora si como quería!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que poner el hover sobre el boton y luego "navegar" con los selectores al elemento que quieras animar a partir de ahi

```css
.primary_color {
  background-color: #dc1921;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.81rem;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #fff;
}

.icono img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 35px;
}

.icono img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.btn:hover .icono img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

b {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.btn:hover b {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn primary_color waves-effect waves-light">
     <span class="icono"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7s0Ddbj.png" alt="Iconos"></span><br>
     <b>LANDSCAPE</b>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que poner el boton como el selector principal para que cuando se haga `hover` **sobre el button**, se le apliquen los estilos a la imagen y al texto que son los hijos:

```css
.primary_color {
  background-color: #dc1921;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.81rem;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #fff;
}

.icono img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 35px;
}

.icono img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}


b {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------*/
button:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

button:hover b{
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn primary_color waves-effect waves-light">
     <span class="icono"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7s0Ddbj.png" alt="Iconos"></span><br>
     <b>LANDSCAPE</b>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.primary_color {
  background-color: #dc1921;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.81rem;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #fff;
}

.icono img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 35px;
}

.icono img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.btn:hover .icono img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

b {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.btn:hover b {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn primary_color waves-effect waves-light">
     <span class="icono"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7s0Ddbj.png" alt="Iconos"></span><br>
     <b>LANDSCAPE</b>
    </button>
```

A veces dudamos del potencial de **CSS** y quizás por ello no probemos cosas por pensar que no podría funcionar. He cambiado tus reglas **CSS** para los `hover`, de tal manera que primero se le vincula el `hover` al botón para posteriormente buscar el elemento al que la regla va a afectar realmente. En tu caso a la `img` y al `b` respectivamente.

Esto manera de seleccionar un elemento funciona porque el botón es padre de los dos elementos que deseamos afectar con la regla **CSS** Si la relación entre ellos fuese "más complicada" ya entraría en juego Javascript, que permite una mayor flexibilidad a la hora de seleccionar nuestros elementos en el **DOM**.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Esta es la forma más adecuada de trabajar con CSS en el ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Saludos checa esto:

```css
.primary_color {
  background-color: #dc1921;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.81rem;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #fff;
}

.icono img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 35px;
}

.icono img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.icono:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

button {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

button:hover {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn primary_color waves-effect waves-light">
     <span class="icono"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7s0Ddbj.png" alt="Iconos"></span><br>
     <b>LANDSCAPE</b>
    </button>
```

fijate que solo estas aplicando mal es CSS deberia ser
**button** no **b** en tus estilos, espero te sirva..!!